# Drawing Geometry inside Grid C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, text, controls

I'm trying to create an outlined text, I've tried using the `ShadowEffect` on the `Label` control but it doesn't provide the desired results and it's quite laggy, the only solution I've found so far is visualizing a `Geometry` build from a `FormattedText` object.

But that also seems to have some problems with it, namely I need to know the Width and the Height of the Control, but for example in a Grid with RowDefinitions, where their size is set to `*`, I cant seem to find a way to obtain the size of the control, thus my Geometry is not being displayed.

Here is my custom control class:

```
public class OutlinedLabel : FrameworkElement
{
    private string _text;
    public string Text
    {
        get => _text;
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            UpdateLayout();
            InvalidateArrange();
            InvalidateMeasure();
            InvalidateVisual();
        }
    }

    public Brush TextColor
    {
        get => (Brush)GetValue(TextColorProperty);
        set => SetValue(TextColorProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(TextColor), typeof(Brush), typeof(OutlinedLabel),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public TextAlignment TextAlignment
    {
        get => (TextAlignment)GetValue(TextAlignmentProperty);
        set => SetValue(TextAlignmentProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextAlignmentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(TextAlignment), typeof(TextAlignment), typeof(OutlinedLabel),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public FontWeight FontWeight
    {
        get => (FontWeight)GetValue(FontWeightProperty);
        set => SetValue(FontWeightProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontWeightProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(FontWeight), typeof(FontWeight), typeof(OutlinedLabel),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));


    public Brush OutlineBrush
    {
        get => (Brush)GetValue(OutlineBrushProperty);
        set => SetValue(OutlineBrushProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty OutlineBrushProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(OutlineBrush), typeof(Brush), typeof(OutlinedLabel),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public double Thickness
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(ThicknessProperty);
        set => SetValue(ThicknessProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ThicknessProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Thickness), typeof(double), typeof(OutlinedLabel),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public FontFamily FontFamily
    {
        get => (FontFamily)GetValue(FontFamilyProperty);
        set => SetValue(FontFamilyProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontFamilyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(FontFamily), typeof(FontFamily), typeof(OutlinedLabel),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public double FontSize
    {
        get => (double) GetValue(FontSizeProperty);
        set => SetValue(FontSizeProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontSizeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(FontSize), typeof(double), typeof(OutlinedLabel),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public OutlinedLabel()
    {
        FontSize = 12;
        Text = string.Empty;
        FontFamily = new FontFamily("Seago UI");
        TextColor = Brushes.Black;
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        var currentOutlineBrush = OutlineBrush ?? TextColor;
        var bg_rect = new Rect(0, 0, ActualWidth, ActualHeight);
        drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Brushes.White, null, bg_rect);

        var typeface = new Typeface(FontFamily.Source);
        var formatted_text = new FormattedText(Text, new CultureInfo("en-us"), FlowDirection, typeface, FontSize,
            currentOutlineBrush);
        formatted_text.SetFontWeight(FontWeight);

        formatted_text.TextAlignment = TextAlignment;

        var origin = new Point(ActualWidth / 2, (ActualHeight - formatted_text.Height) / 2);

        var geometry = formatted_text.BuildGeometry(origin);

        var pen = new Pen(currentOutlineBrush, Thickness);
        drawingContext.DrawGeometry(TextColor, pen, geometry);
    }
}
```

Here is my xaml:

```
    <Grid Name="gridSubs" Margin="0,0,0,118" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsHitTestVisible="false">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Viewbox StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Uniform" Grid.Row="8">
            <customControls:OutlinedLabel TextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" OutlineBrush="Black" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="32" Thickness="1"/>
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Uniform" Grid.Row="7">
            <customControls:OutlinedLabel TextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" OutlineBrush="Black" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="32" Thickness="1"/>
        </Viewbox>
        //...
    </Grid>
```

When I set the `Text` property, `OnRender` is being invoked, but nothing visually happens, `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` both have a value of 0.

The class works if I create for example an OutlinedLabel not contained in a Grid.

How can I make it work in this specific case?

Comment: Although this doesn't answer your question directly, I'd suggest that you should go the route of creating a `ShaderEffect`. Some samples can be seen here: http://wpffx.codeplex.com/ of how to create effects, then you merely apply the effect to the Label instead of creating a custom class.

Comment: I'd like to add that I'm also open to alternative solutions achieving the same goal - text with outline.

Comment: I have never created a shader effect myself, but that sample library is a perfect start. You might be able to find an "outline text" shader effect already out there considering that game developers use shaders a lot, and I'm sure someone wrote an FX to do this already.

Comment: Are you actually "open to alternative solutions achieving the same goal"?

Comment: @Clemens - yes I am. As long as they are fully working and offer some advantage over mine.

Comment: What exactly isn't working with the solution I suggested? Is there anything you don't understand? Feel free to ask.

Comment: @Clemens your solution lacks text alignment which really screws up the positioning obviously and I'd like to have the required external project's files included in the answer.

Comment: Check it out now. I've changed it to use FormattedText instead of GlyphRun and also to take TextAlignment into account. The important part however is that it overrides `MeasureOverride` in order to determine its `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight`, which it already did before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This OutlinedText control works. The important part is that it overrides `MeasureOverride` in order to determine its `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight`.

```
public class OutlinedText : FrameworkElement
{
    private FormattedText text;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = TextBlock.TextProperty.AddOwner(
        typeof(OutlinedText), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((o, e) => ((OutlinedText)o).text = null) { AffectsMeasure = true });

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextAlignmentProperty = TextBlock.TextAlignmentProperty.AddOwner(
        typeof(OutlinedText), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((o, e) => ((OutlinedText)o).text = null) { AffectsRender = true });

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontSizeProperty = TextBlock.FontSizeProperty.AddOwner(
        typeof(OutlinedText), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((o, e) => ((OutlinedText)o).text = null) { AffectsMeasure = true });

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontFamilyProperty = TextBlock.FontFamilyProperty.AddOwner(
        typeof(OutlinedText), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((o, e) => ((OutlinedText)o).text = null) { AffectsMeasure = true });

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontStyleProperty = TextBlock.FontStyleProperty.AddOwner(
        typeof(OutlinedText), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((o, e) => ((OutlinedText)o).text = null) { AffectsMeasure = true });

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontWeightProperty = TextBlock.FontWeightProperty.AddOwner(
        typeof(OutlinedText), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((o, e) => ((OutlinedText)o).text = null) { AffectsMeasure = true });

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontStretchProperty = TextBlock.FontStretchProperty.AddOwner(
        typeof(OutlinedText), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((o, e) => ((OutlinedText)o).text = null) { AffectsMeasure = true });

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ForegroundProperty = TextBlock.ForegroundProperty.AddOwner(
        typeof(OutlinedText), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((o, e) => ((OutlinedText)o).text = null) { AffectsRender = true });

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundProperty = TextBlock.BackgroundProperty.AddOwner(
        typeof(OutlinedText), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((o, e) => ((OutlinedText)o).text = null) { AffectsRender = true });

    public static readonly DependencyProperty OutlineBrushProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(OutlineBrush), typeof(Brush), typeof(OutlinedText),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Brushes.White, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, (o, e) => ((OutlinedText)o).text = null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty OutlineThicknessProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(OutlineThickness), typeof(double), typeof(OutlinedText),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(1d, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure, (o, e) => ((OutlinedText)o).text = null));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public TextAlignment TextAlignment
    {
        get { return (TextAlignment)GetValue(TextAlignmentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextAlignmentProperty, value); }
    }

    [TypeConverter(typeof(FontSizeConverter))]
    public double FontSize
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(FontSizeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FontSizeProperty, value); }
    }

    public FontFamily FontFamily
    {
        get { return (FontFamily)GetValue(FontFamilyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FontFamilyProperty, value); }
    }

    public FontStyle FontStyle
    {
        get { return (FontStyle)GetValue(FontStyleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FontStyleProperty, value); }
    }

    public FontWeight FontWeight
    {
        get { return (FontWeight)GetValue(FontWeightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FontWeightProperty, value); }
    }

    public FontStretch FontStretch
    {
        get { return (FontStretch)GetValue(FontStretchProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FontStretchProperty, value); }
    }

    public Brush Foreground
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(ForegroundProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ForegroundProperty, value); }
    }

    public Brush Background
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(BackgroundProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BackgroundProperty, value); }
    }

    public Brush OutlineBrush
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(OutlineBrushProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OutlineBrushProperty, value); }
    }

    public double OutlineThickness
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(OutlineThicknessProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OutlineThicknessProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        var size = CheckText() ? new Size(text.Width, text.Height) : new Size();

        if (!double.IsNaN(Width) && size.Width < Width)
        {
            size.Width = Width;
        }

        if (!double.IsNaN(Height) && size.Height < Height)
        {
            size.Height = Height;
        }

        return size;
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        if (CheckText())
        {
            var size = DesiredSize;
            var origin = new Point();

            if (size.Width > text.Width)
            {
                if (TextAlignment == TextAlignment.Center)
                {
                    origin.X = ((size.Width - text.Width) - OutlineThickness) / 2;
                }
                else if (TextAlignment == TextAlignment.Right)
                {
                    origin.X = (size.Width - text.Width) - OutlineThickness;
                }
            }

            if (size.Height > text.Height)
            {
                origin.Y = (size.Height - text.Height) / 2;
            }

            if (Background != null)
            {
                drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Background, null, new Rect(size));
            }

            drawingContext.DrawGeometry(Foreground, new Pen(OutlineBrush, OutlineThickness), text.BuildGeometry(origin));
        }
    }

    private bool CheckText()
    {
        if (text == null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text))
            {
                return false;
            }

            text = new FormattedText(
                Text, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                new Typeface(FontFamily, FontStyle, FontWeight, FontStretch),
                FontSize, Brushes.Black);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice.  A couple suggestions: (1) add `[TypeConverter(typeof(FontSizeConverter))]` to the `FontSize` property; (2) it's not obvious that `Background` is used to set the outline brush--maybe add an `OutlineBrush` property?; (3) I'd include a default style that initializes `Foreground` to `Transparent` and `OutlineBrush` to the system text color.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `ViewBox`. Your control needs to know/evaluate its own size in order to work within a `ViewBox` correctly. Just remove the ViewBox for a test and you'll see the appears. When you set `Height` and `Width` of `OutlinedLabel` the text also appears.

You might consider to respond to `MeasureOverride` and return the desired size.

In general I don't consider it best practice to use a ViewBox to overcome sizing problems of a control. The control should handle all that.